# System service running as user is terminated on logout

Tags: systemd, users, services, logout

I have a system service that is executed for selected users. Name is `serv@<uid>` (`<uid>` is UID of the user). I want to share user's resource limits with the service (place it into `user-<uid>.slice`) and I also want to use his permissions.

`/etc/systemd/system/serv@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=My service for user %i

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/serv.sh
Restart=always
User=%i
Slice=user-%i.slice
SuccessExitStatus=0 255 SIGKILL SIGTERM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

When the user logs out, the service is terminated using SIGTERM. Why isn't the service restarted? How can I set it up so the service will not be terminated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change logind configuration:

`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

```
[Login]
…
KillUserProcesses=no
…
```

This also changes behavior for other services and background processes (like `screen`, `tmux`). See [issue #3483](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3483);

---

Run `systemctl restart systemd-logind` after that.

Comment: I use `tmux` and others so it will solve multiple problems at once.

Answer (score 14):

For me the solution was `loginctl enable-linger username`. Without this the service would die when the user logged out. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day!

Comment: THIS WAS IT. Thank you @burneddi